# Numeric Macro in SAS

Tags: sas, macros

I have a variable for counting days. I'm trying to use the day count to divide by total days.

How do I create a macro that stores the most recent day and allows me to quote it later?

This is what I have so far (I've cut out code that's not relevant)

```
DATA scotland;
input day deathsscotland casesscotland;
cards;
1 1 85 
2 1 121 
3 1 153 
4 1 171 
5 2 195 
6 3 227  
7 6 266 
8 6 322
9 7 373 
10 10 416
11 14 499
12 16 584 
13 22 719
14 25 894
;
run;

proc sort data=scotland out=scotlandsort;
by day;
run;


Data _null_;
keep day;
set scotlandsort end=eof;
if eof then output;
run;

%let daycountscot = day

Data ratio;
set cdratio;
SCOTLANDAVERAGE = (SCOTLANDRATIO/&daycountscot)*1000;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your own code, you can create the macro variable like this

```
Data _null_;
keep day;
set scotlandsort end=eof;
if eof then call symputx('daycountscot', day);
run;

%put &daycountscot.;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `data _null_` is not doing anything.  You can eliminate the `sort` and `data` steps by selecting the max day value directly into a macro variable.

```
proc sql noprint;
  select max(day) into :daycountscot trimmed
  from scotland
  ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use macro code for this, it is better to keep values in variables anyway.  To convert the value into text to store it as a macro variable SAS will have to round the number.

You could make a dataset with the maximum DAY value and then combine it with the dataset where you want to do the division.

```
data last_day;
  set scotlandsort end=eof;
  if eof then output;
  keep day;
  rename day=last_day;
run;

data ratio;
  set cdratio;
  if _n_=1 then set last_day;
  SCOTLANDAVERAGE = (SCOTLANDRATIO/last_day)*1000;
run;
```

Probably easier in SQL code:

```
proc sql;
create table ratio as 
  select a.*, (SCOTLANDRATIO/last_day)*1000 as SCOTLANDAVERAGE 
  from cdratio a
     , (select max(day) as last_day from scotland)
;
quit;
```